# Utils.MatlabToNET() is returing same date for two different dates

Tags: c#, matlab, datetime, time-series

I am doing time-series analysis. Same date is causing collision in Dictionary which results in one day of data loss. Any way to get one to one mapping of dates while conversion ?

var val = Utils.MatlabToNET(734570)).ToOADate();

var val2 = Utils.MatlabToNET(734571)).ToOADate();

// Both val and val2 have values 40602 which is "2/28/2011 12:00:00 AM"

Comment: Your dictionary needs to have a list in the value to contain duplicate keys Dictionary<DataTime, List<object>>, where object should be changed as required.

Comment: I am loosing one day of data point which is valuable to me

Comment: Having a list in a dictionary doesn't loose data.  Both points are still in the list.  It looks like ToOADate is truncating the DateTime object to midnight so you have duplicates.  The right solution is to include the hours/minutes in the time.  A DateTime object is a double with the integer portion the Day and the fractional part the fraction of a day like 3 hours/ 24 hours (3AM) = .125

Comment: I am getting time-series data as input from other source. Require to process the data without touching the dates. Why two different dates gets converted to single day ?

Comment: The fractional part of the DateTime is being dropped (or not being set properly).  Possibly getting cast to an integer instead of a single/double.